# How to fix the clang error "clang frontend command failed with exit code 139" when compiling the Android 12 source code?

Tags: compilation, clang, android-source

I have bought an orange pi 5B, and I want to use android 12 on this platform. When I compile the source code, the step "starting ninja", it will report an error.

```
============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
PLATFORM_VERSION=12
TARGET_PRODUCT=rk3588s_s
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=userdebug
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_ARCH=arm64
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv8-a
TARGET_CPU_VARIANT=generic
TARGET_2ND_ARCH=arm
TARGET_2ND_ARCH_VARIANT=armv8-a
TARGET_2ND_CPU_VARIANT=generic
HOST_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_2ND_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=linux
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Linux-6.2.0-26-generic-x86_64-Ubuntu-22.04.3-LTS
HOST_CROSS_OS=windows
HOST_CROSS_ARCH=x86
HOST_CROSS_2ND_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=SQ3A.220605.009.B1
OUT_DIR=out
============================================
#58 0x0000000005283ca9 _start (prebuilts/clang/host/linux-x86/clang-r416183b1/bin/clang++.real+0x5283ca9)
clang++: error: clang frontend command failed with exit code 139 (use -v to see invocation)
Android (7485623, based on r416183b1) clang version 12.0.7 (https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/llvm-project c935d99d7cf2016289302412d708641d52d2f7ee)
Target: aarch64-unknown-linux-android10000
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: prebuilts/clang/host/linux-x86/clang-r416183b1/bin
clang++: note: diagnostic msg: 
********************

PLEASE ATTACH THE FOLLOWING FILES TO THE BUG REPORT:
Preprocessed source(s) and associated run script(s) are located at:
clang++: note: diagnostic msg: /home/xkcx/Downloads/Android_12/out/soong/.temp/SelectionDAGDumper-2b0770.cpp
clang++: note: diagnostic msg: /home/xkcx/Downloads/Android_12/out/soong/.temp/SelectionDAGDumper-2b0770.sh
clang++: note: diagnostic msg: 
********************
17:23:39 ninja failed with: exit status 1


#### failed to build some targets (09:24 (mm:ss)) ####
```

I searcher on the internet, but no similar conditions for this bug.
So what can I do for this, Is it caused by a corrupted file?

At first, I think I need to install a clang compiler on my ubuntu system, and I install the clang version 14. But it doesn't work.